# InDesign – Text breaking across pages

Tags: adobe-indesign

[image]

I'm typesetting a long document with a lot of text, and sometimes paragraphs are breaking across pages seemingly randomly like in the screenshot. I tried to see if it had something to do with my paragraph styles & keep options, but apparently it doesn't. So I'm really confused why its doing this.

Comment: Could you replace the screen shot with one in normal mode instead of preview mode? That would give some information about the structure of the pages.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet just added a different screenshot. Let me know if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it rules out that it’s just the text frame ending higher up on the page at least…

Comment: Try this: Create a new document, from scratch. Copy a chunk (several pages) of text into something like BBEdit or Notepad to strip out *all* formatting. Copy this unformatted text and paste it into the new document. That should solve the problem. You can then experiment with copying *formatted* text over a little at a time until you uncover one of the weird breaks, and then you have at least narrowed it down to that paragraph. Clean the formatting off that one and you should be okay. As for why? Can't really say without having the doc in hand.

Comment: Does this happen when you change the para style? i.e. to Basic. Any chance you have a hidden layer with wrapping elements? Also I would love to see a screenshot of the paragraph style...

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Ill try that - kind of thought I needed to do that instead of copy/pasting from Word

Comment: Do you mean your original source copy is from Word, or are you describing pasting IND copy into Word to "strip formatting"? Because if your original copy is from Word and you're just pasting into InDesign, good grief, who the hell knows what kind of cruft is infesting your text.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I mean the source copy is from Word. Yeah I think from now on Ill do like what you said above and strip all formatting instead of c/v from Word.

Comment: Alternately you can dump the text to Adobe Tagged Text format, then examine that in a text editor --- it shows you how InDesign actually has the text marked up internally.

Comment: @WillAdams how do you do that?

Comment: Select a text flow you want to export and do File | Export and chose "Adobe InDesign Tagged Text (*.txt)" from the Save as type drop-down.

Comment: Cool - didn't know you could do that

Comment: This looks like a combination of Keep Together and Keep With Next. The only paragraph that got broken is the longest one.

Answer (score 1):

Keep Options can cause this kind of behavior. If some paragraphs are set to keep all lines together, and are set to stay with the next or previous X lines, it can cause unexpected paragraph breaks like you have there. See image:

It can be hard to identify where keep options have been applied. To test, select all of the text in the story and disable all keeps options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps those paragraphs have "column" breaks, opposed to a regular paragraph break. A "column" break is when you use the "Enter" key instead of the "Return" key. This can cause things to jump. Turn on "show hidden characters" under the TYPE menu to make sure.

[image: EXAMPLE:]

Comment: Im using a lot of page breaks in the document, but you can see in the screenshot not where the text jumps. I thought it might be that too.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to miss hidden characters when the text is justified. Have a look with the text set to left aligned.

Comment: I definitely agree. I did look but there was no break character where the breaks were happening.